# Get days difference between two datetimes in SparkSQL

Tags: date, datetime, apache-spark-sql, datediff

I want to get the **integer** days difference between two datetimes in SparkSQL, but it ignores the time part and returns a different result than expected.

For example, the query below returns 9, but I expected 8:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CAST('2021-07-10 02:26:16' AS TIMESTAMP), CAST('2021-07-01 19:10:28' AS TIMESTAMP))
```

I can achieve the expected result by converting the datetime to long, so I can get the seconds difference between them and convert the result to days, casting to integer, like:

```
SELECT CAST((CAST(CAST('2021-07-10 02:26:16' AS TIMESTAMP) AS LONG) - CAST(CAST('2021-07-01 19:10:28' AS TIMESTAMP) AS LONG))/(60*60*24) AS INTEGER)
```

I wanted to know if there is a 'more recommended way' of doing that, like using some built-in SparkSQL function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the [`extract` SQL function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/sql/index.html#extract) and apply it to the interval (difference of two timestamps).

> Extracts a part of the date/timestamp or **interval** source

*) `extract` function is available in Spark from version 3.x on.

See example below

```
WITH input AS (
    select TIMESTAMP'2021-07-10 02:26:16' t2,
           TIMESTAMP'2021-07-01 19:10:28' t1
)
SELECT
    datediff(t2, t1) `datediff`,
    extract(day FROM t2-t1) `extract`
FROM input
```

returns

| datediff | extract |
| --- | --- |
| 9 | 8 |

Comment: I tried this code but it failed with this error: AnalysisException: cannot resolve '(input.`t2` - input.`t1`)' due to data type mismatch: '(input.`t2` - input.`t1`)' requires (numeric or calendarinterval) type, not timestamp;

Comment: Which spark version are you using? Mine was run using Spark `3.0.1`.

Comment: it's v2.4.5. Maybe this is why it failed then. I liked your suggestion, it looks fancier to me. Tks!